# Hackerland Radio Transmitter

Tags: python

```
def hackerlandRadioTransmitters(x, k):
    x = set(sorted(x))
    x = list(x)
    i = 0
    # no.of transmitters installed
    count = 0
    while (i < len(x)):
        # current location
        loc = x[i]
        # initialized an incrementing variable j
        # incremented till a suitable place to install a transmitter is found
        j = i
        while (True):
            # if the end of the array is found, place a transmitter at the end and return count
            if (j >= len(x) - 1):
                count += 1
                return count
            # increasing j by 1 in each iteration and checking if the distance exceeds k
            if (x[j] - loc < k):
                j += 1
            # if it exceeds k, or is equal to k a transmitter is placed and i is changed to the index of the next uncovered house.
            else:
                count += 1
                i = j + 1
                # took note to change the location to the place where transmitter is installed.
                loc = x[i - 1]
                break
        
        # initialized an incrementing variable to find the next uncovered house
        p = i
        while (True):
            # if the end of array is found before finding the next uncovered house simply return the count
            if (p >= len(x) - 1):
                return count
            if (x[p] - loc < k):
                p += 1
            else:
                i = p + 1
                break
            
    return count
```

[Link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/hackerland-radio-transmitters/problem?isFullScreen=true)

The code fails 18/31 times.
Can anyone help me figure out where I'm wrong

My goal was to first find the leftmost uncovered house and then install a transmitter in the rightmost house such that it covers the house in the left. After placing a transmitter I would try to find another house which is uncovered. And repeated the process.

Comment: 1 character variable names are saying nothing. Also, try to extract methods which have names so we know what they are supposed to do.

Comment: And get rid of superfluous parantheses. They make the code more difficult to read (e.g. `while (True):` -> `while True:`, `if (j >= len(x) - 1):` -> `if j >= len(x) - 1:`).

Comment: I added a bunch of comments to understand the code better. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have now added comments to explain what your code does. That doesn't make stuff better. Rename the variables instead. If `count` counts the transmitters, name it `transmitterCount`. If `loc` is the current location, name it `currentLocation`. If `j` is an index, name it `index`.